# Change the page filter on pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I may resort to using multiple pivot tables if I cannot do this but I want to give it a try anyway.

Basically, I have a sheet with a pretty good amount of rows (45k+) and I want to use a pivot table to group items together so that I can get uniques only to then match them in an Access database and add new items only. I have to do that for a few columns and so I thought that filtering the table using VBA could be a good solution though I have not been able to achieve it. From MSDN I understand that it is possible to add filters using PivotFields.Add though I get an error "Argument or incorrect procedure call" (or something like that). Here's what I have tried:

```
Me.PivotTables("tcd_transits").PivotFields("NOTE").ClearAllFilters
Me.PivotTables("tcd_transits").PivotFields("NOTE").PivotFilters.Add _
                xlValueEquals, "NOTE", "RUBRIQUES"
```

The first line effectively clears the filters but the second doesn't add a filter on "NOTE" for "RUBRIQUES" and throws the error I mentionned above. Am I completely off the path here or is there a detail I missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it here:

http://excel.bigresource.com/Track/excel-0anuDfeJ/

The solution is to use `PivotFields.CurrentPage`

```
    Me.PivotTables("tcd_transits").PivotFields("NOTE").CurrentPage = "TRANSITS"
```

Comment: I usually hack this one by using VBA to change the cell value where the filter is located